# How to change UISearchBar Placeholder and image tint color?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uikit

I've been trying search results for hours, but I can't get this figured out. Perhaps it isn't possible. I'm trying to change the tint color of the placeholder text and magnifying glass of a UISearchBar. I'm only targeting iOS 8.0+ if that matters. Here's my code and what it looks like now:

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar()
searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal
searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

[image: a busy cat]

I'd like for the search and magnifying glass to be white, or perhaps a dark green.

Comment: seachControl.searchBar.placeholder = ""

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you have a custom image you could use, you can set the image and change the placeholder text color using something similar to the following:

```
[searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchWhite"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];

UITextField *searchTextField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];    
if ([searchTextField respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedPlaceholder:)]) {
    UIColor *color = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [searchTextField setAttributedPlaceholder:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Search" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}]];
}
```

In that example I used purpleColor, instead you can use the `+ (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha` method to create your custom dark green color.

EDIT: I just realized you were writing it in swift... duh. Quickly typed this out so I didn't leave the answer in just Obj-C.

```
    searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "SearchWhite"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal);

    var searchTextField: UITextField? = searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField
    if searchTextField!.respondsToSelector(Selector("attributedPlaceholder")) {
        var color = UIColor.purpleColor()
        let attributeDict = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.purpleColor()]
        searchTextField!.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "search", attributes: attributeDict)
    }
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
    var searchTextField: UITextField? = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
    if searchTextField!.responds(to: #selector(getter: UITextField.attributedPlaceholder)) {
        let attributeDict = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        searchTextField!.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: attributeDict)
    }
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you _so much_. I hadn't seen `searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField` before, which is brilliant. Any chance you know how to change the clear button (the little round x) as well?

Comment: I would imagine it would be the same way as the setImage but instead of using the UISearchBarIcon.Search, you would instead use .Clear??? I haven't actually tried that though. Outside of that I know the actual word "Cancel" is affected by the searchBar.tintColor...

Comment: Accessing private properties or APIs is a sure way to get your app rejected.

Comment: don't use private APIs

Answer (score 106):

### Details

- Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a), iOS 13, swift 5

### Solution

```
import UIKit

extension UISearchBar {

    func getTextField() -> UITextField? { return value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField }
    func set(textColor: UIColor) { if let textField = getTextField() { textField.textColor = textColor } }
    func setPlaceholder(textColor: UIColor) { getTextField()?.setPlaceholder(textColor: textColor) }
    func setClearButton(color: UIColor) { getTextField()?.setClearButton(color: color) }

    func setTextField(color: UIColor) {
        guard let textField = getTextField() else { return }
        switch searchBarStyle {
        case .minimal:
            textField.layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
            textField.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        case .prominent, .default: textField.backgroundColor = color
        @unknown default: break
        }
    }

    func setSearchImage(color: UIColor) {
        guard let imageView = getTextField()?.leftView as? UIImageView else { return }
        imageView.tintColor = color
        imageView.image = imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    }
}

private extension UITextField {

    private class Label: UILabel {
        private var _textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        override var textColor: UIColor! {
            set { super.textColor = _textColor }
            get { return _textColor }
        }

        init(label: UILabel, textColor: UIColor = .lightGray) {
            _textColor = textColor
            super.init(frame: label.frame)
            self.text = label.text
            self.font = label.font
        }

        required init?(coder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: coder) }
    }


    private class ClearButtonImage {
        static private var _image: UIImage?
        static private var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
        static func getImage(closure: @escaping (UIImage?)->()) {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
                semaphore.wait()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let image = _image { closure(image); semaphore.signal(); return }
                    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first else { semaphore.signal(); return }
                    let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -200, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
                    window.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(searchBar)
                    searchBar.text = "txt"
                    searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
                    _image = searchBar.getTextField()?.getClearButton()?.image(for: .normal)
                    closure(_image)
                    searchBar.removeFromSuperview()
                    semaphore.signal()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func setClearButton(color: UIColor) {
        ClearButtonImage.getImage { [weak self] image in
            guard   let image = image,
                let button = self?.getClearButton() else { return }
            button.imageView?.tintColor = color
            button.setImage(image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        }
    }

    var placeholderLabel: UILabel? { return value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel }

    func setPlaceholder(textColor: UIColor) {
        guard let placeholderLabel = placeholderLabel else { return }
        let label = Label(label: placeholderLabel, textColor: textColor)
        setValue(label, forKey: "placeholderLabel")
    }

    func getClearButton() -> UIButton? { return value(forKey: "clearButton") as? UIButton }
}
```

### Full Sample

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .default
        view.addSubview(searchBar)

        searchBar.placeholder = "placeholder"
        searchBar.set(textColor: .brown)
        searchBar.setTextField(color: UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.3))
        searchBar.setPlaceholder(textColor: .white)
        searchBar.setSearchImage(color: .white)
        searchBar.setClearButton(color: .red)
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work on iOS 11 when SearchBar is within the NavigationBar without success. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello Renato. I can't understand your problem. You can't add SearchBar to NavigationBar?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Magnifying glass and search placeholder not in centre as per your output.

Comment: This solution looks great, but for `UISearchController` you need to subclass both `UISearchController` and it's `UISearchBar`. Even then, the clear button coloring still doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: This is a good solution but it can easily be broken if Apple decides to change the internal subview structure of UISearchBar in a future iOS release. I'm amazed they don't expose simple appearance customisations like this as a public API.

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk Great answer. In swift 4 I think NSForegroundColorAttributeName has been changed to NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.

Comment: Great Solution! One issue is `ClearButtonColor` is not working in iOS 12.0.

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk I think what @Renato meant was if you add the searchController straight to the navigationItem like this `navigationItem.searchController = searchController`, these methods don't work. I noticed however if you add the searchBar of the searchController to the titleView of the navigationItem like this, `navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar`, it works.

Comment: @Isuru It can be true. Because `searchController` has own `searchBar`. In this case I suggest to inherit `searchController` and updated its  `searchBar`.

Comment: Searchbar's placeholder color is not changing on iOS 13.

Answer (score 12):

Swift 3: If you want to change the placeholder, clearbutton and magnifier glass

```
    let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
    textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = UIColor.white

    let textFieldInsideSearchBarLabel = textFieldInsideSearchBar!.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
    textFieldInsideSearchBarLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

    let clearButton = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.value(forKey: "clearButton") as! UIButton
    clearButton.setImage(clearButton.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    clearButton.tintColor = UIColor.white

    let glassIconView = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.leftView as? UIImageView

    glassIconView?.image = glassIconView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    glassIconView?.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: self.searcBar.setTextFieldColor(color: .white) not working why ? still showing light lightGray color, but other colors are  working but white not working any idea ? ....

Answer (score 3):

You can change the color of the text without violating the private api rule:

```
UILabel.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UITextField.self]).textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses is only available in ios9+

Answer (score 2):

I could not make it work properly with any of the above solutions.

I created the following UISearchBar category which works properly on **iOS 8.4** and **10.3**:

**UISearchBar+PlaceholderColor.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UISearchBar (PlaceholderColor)

- (void)setPlaceholderColor:(UIColor *)placeholderColor;

@end
```

**UISearchBar+PlaceholderColor.m**

```
#import "UISearchBar+PlaceholderColor.h"

@implementation UISearchBar (PlaceholderColor)

- (void)setPlaceholderColor:(UIColor *)placeholderColor {
    UILabel *labelView = [self searchBarTextFieldLabelFromView:self];
    [labelView setTextColor:placeholderColor];
}

- (UILabel *)searchBarTextFieldLabelFromView:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *v in [view subviews]) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            return (UILabel *)v;
        }

        UIView *labelView = [self searchBarTextFieldLabelFromView:v];
        if (labelView) {
            return (UILabel *)labelView;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

**USAGE**:

```
[mySearchBar setPlaceholderColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

Make sure that you call setPlaceholderColor: **AFTER** your UISearchBar has been added to the view and has created its view hierarchy.

If you open your search bar programmatically, call it **AFTER** your becomeFirstResponder call, as such:

```
[mySearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
[searchBar setPlaceholderColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Otherwise, if you are leveraging **UISearchBarDelegate**:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar setPlaceholderColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a Swift 4.1 search bar extension:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
extension UISearchBar{
    func setTextField(placeHolderColor:UIColor = .gray,placeHolder:String = "Search Something",textColor:UIColor = .white,backgroundColor:UIColor = .black,
                      placeHolderFont:UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0),
                      textFont:UIFont =  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0) ){
        for item in self.subviews{
            for mainView in (item as UIView).subviews{
                mainView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
                if mainView is UITextField{
                    let textField = mainView as? UITextField
                    if let _textF = textField{
                        _textF.text = "success"
                        _textF.textColor = textColor
                        _textF.font      = textFont
                        _textF.attributedPlaceholder = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: placeHolder, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : placeHolderColor,
                                                                                                                               NSAttributedStringKey.font : placeHolderFont])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this for your `searchBar` like this :

```
controller.searchBar.setTextField(placeHolderColor: .white,
 placeHolder: "Search A Pet",
 textColor: .white,
 backgroundColor: .green,
 placeHolderFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0),
 textFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UISearchBar {
    var textField: UITextField? { return value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField }
    var placeholderLabel: UILabel? { return textField?.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel }
    var icon: UIImageView? { return textField?.leftView as? UIImageView }
    var iconColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return icon?.tintColor
        }
        set {
            icon?.image = icon?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            icon?.tintColor = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! Icon works fine, placeholder text doesn't change for me though.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to change the textfiled in search bar.
It works in swift 3 and Xcode8.

Firstly, subclass the UISearchBar class.

```
class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {
```

UISearchBar include a view which has the important textfield you wanted. Following function get the index in subviews.

```
func indexOfSearchFieldInSubviews() -> Int! {
    var index: Int!
    let searchBarView = subviews[0]
    for (i, subview) in searchBarView.subviews.enumerated() {
        if subview.isKind(of: UITextField.self) {
            index = i
            break
        }
    }
    return index
}


override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Find the index of the search field in the search bar subviews.
    if let index = indexOfSearchFieldInSubviews() {
        // Access the search field
        let searchField: UITextField = subviews[0].subviews[index] as! UITextField
        // Set its frame.
        searchField.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: frame.size.width - 10, height: frame.size.height - 10)
        // Set the font and text color of the search field.
        searchField.font = preferredFont
        searchField.textColor = preferredTextColor

        // Set the placeholder and its color
        let attributesDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: preferredPlaceholderColor.cgColor]
        searchField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: preferredPlaceholder, attributes: attributesDictionary)

        // Set the background color of the search field.
        searchField.backgroundColor = barTintColor
    }

    super.draw(rect)
}
```

There you go, enjoy for this.

Comment: Do you have the source code for this? I am having trouble understanding this.

Comment: Hi @ethanfox27, here is the source code, hope for help.
https://github.com/JeromeTW/XZY-s-Blog/blob/master/ReadMe.txt

https://github.com/JeromeTW/XZY-s-Blog/blob/master/CustomSearchBar.swift

Answer (score 1):

Small update to Vasily Bodnarchuk's great answer.

Swift 4+

`NSForegroundColorAttributeName` has been changed to `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor`

Answer (score 0):

For anybody just trying to change the text and having trouble seeing the updated placeholder, it worked for me by putting it here instead of `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.searchBar.placeholder = @"My Custom Text";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found this thread, sorry about the bump given the age. However it helped me in trying to fix my issue, and adding onto @m_katsifarakis answer, I added more to his existing category.

Adding additional color + font support for both placeholder and input text.

Only tested on iOS 13 as that's all I am supporting.

```
@interface UISearchBar (ColorandFont)
- (void)setPlaceholderColor:(UIColor *)placeholderColor setPlaceholderFont:(UIFont *)placeholderFont;
- (void)setTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor setTextFont:(UIFont *)textFont;
@end
@implementation UISearchBar (ColorandFont)

//Placeholder Color
- (void)setPlaceholderColor:(UIColor *)placeholderColor setPlaceholderFont:(UIFont *)placeholderFont{
    UILabel *labelView = [self placeholderText:self];
    [labelView setTextColor:placeholderColor];
    [labelView setFont:placeholderFont];
}
- (UILabel *)placeholderText:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *v in [view subviews]) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            return (UILabel *)v;
        }

        UIView *labelView = [self placeholderText:v];
        if (labelView) {
            return (UILabel *)labelView;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

//Text Color
- (void)setTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor setTextFont:(UIFont *)textFont{
    UITextField *textView = [self searchBarText:self];
    [textView setTextColor:textColor];
    [textView setFont:textFont];
}
- (UITextField *)searchBarText:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *v in [view subviews]) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            return (UITextField *)v;
        }

        UIView *textView = [self searchBarText:v];
        if (textView) {
            return (UITextField *)textView;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
@end
```

Usage (I used in viewDidLoad and Appear) given my current setup, results may vary:

```
[self.searchBar setPlaceholderColor:[UIColor lightTextColor] setPlaceholderFont:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:13]];
[self.searchBar setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor] setTextFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
```

Answer (score -3):

In Swift 4, assuming your search controller is set like this:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

then set placeholder text as follows:

```
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Here is my custom text"
```

Comment: The question is how to change the colors, not how to set the text