# change textbox alignment in search bar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I want to change **text alignment** of Placeholder in Searchcontroller **searchBar**.

I used this Swift code to create search bar in my navigation controller:

```
@IBAction func searchwithAddress(_ sender: Any) {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultController)
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    definesPresentationContext = true
    self.present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

How can I use textalign for my searchbar?

Comment: You have to create custom controller for that, [Here is what you looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41745002/8527224)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [link](https://medium.com/@maximbilan/ios-left-aligned-uisearchbar-b51ef36b6e1b) to change the alignment of Placeholder in search bar.

But I would suggest to create your own search bar using UITextField and UIImageView, and responding to the delegate calls.